# Trigger in multiple schema

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have one database with two schema: `schema1` and `schema2`.
I want to create trigger for `SCHEMA1.CLIENT` table. When ever update query performed in `SCHEMA1.CLIENT` table before the changes and after the change rows will added in `SCHEMA2.HISTORY` table.

Example:

```
SCHEMA1.CLIENT

NAME    AGE DEPT
KRANTHI 21  CSE
KUMAR   22  ME
```

If I update above table `kranthi` age from `21` to `33`, the rows will be stored like below in `SCHEMA2.HISTORY`.

```
SCHEMA2.HISTORY

MODIFIE  DNAME   AGE    DEPT
BEFORE  KRANTHI  21     CSE
AFTER   KRANTHI  33     CSE
```

Comment: Added `oracle` tag based on `plsql`

Comment: Was there a question?